# How to hide row border in grid

Tags: css

I have a grid that contains links and an image inside the link. it doesn't display column borders, but row border. how can I remove the row border?

A working example can be found here: http://lineeldor.no/home/mosaic

**CSS**:

```
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(108px, 1fr));
grid-template-rows: auto;
border: 22px solid #282828;
background-color: #282828;
```

Comment: I see that the issue really is the images not fitting the entire space, leaving that small border at the bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a look at the example you provided, I notice the issue itself is that the grid items don't have a set height; the images inside each box have a `max-width` and a `width` set up, so it is leaving some space on the bottom of the box which makes it look like a border.

One solution I found was setting a max height on the grid items so they don't create more space than necessary.

On the grid container itself I set a height for each row.

```
section.mosaic {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit,minmax(128px,1fr));
    grid-template-rows: 137px;
    border: 22px solid #282828;
    background-color: #282828;
}
```

As well as this for each anchor tag.

```
a.item {
    max-height: 137px;
}
```

Ended up looking like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would add `margin:0; padding:0` to the anchor tags just to be sure. But... Is it possible to **remove the line return After the image and before the** ?

I don't know why, but line returns after image tags that should be ignored in HTML have historically caused issues like that.

so
`<img... /></a>` instead of:

```
<img.../>
</a>
```

Otherwise, you could explicitly set the size of the `anchor` and then absolutely position the image inside that tag using `top:0; right:0; bottom:0; left:0;` That "should" force it to ignore that spacing but it might also stretch the images slightly.